# Threading emails onto a lead

Tags: rest-api, email, singleemailmessage

I'm working on a project that takes care of sending emails to customers who sign up with us.  The project automatically creates a new Lead for every customer that signs up, but we next want to store a record of outbound emails we have sent to the Lead on their record.

At worse case we can cram it into a Task, but is there a way to create an EmailMessage?  I'm attempting to call the API for it (/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/EmailMessage) and I'm getting  "The requested resource does not exist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email message object is only available as a child of the case object.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_support.htm

I would either create a task or create a custom object to track those emails.

Comment: A task using the raw text of the email in the description would work pretty well.  You could also add a rich text area to tasks if you wanted the html format.  You might also have noticed the html email status object on leads, which is held in the `EmailStatus` object.  Unfortunately the object is pretty much useless outside the UI since you can't query, create, or update it.